# Does Postgres Replication (native) support per-database level replication?

Tags: database, postgresql, replication

Does Postgres Replication mechanimsm native support per-database level replication? I mean if we have db1, db2, db3 in one Postgresq Process, could I configure to control Postgres only replicate db1 data to standby Postgresq?

thanks, 
Emre

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Built-in replication support only server to server replication. Third party replication systems can support replication on database level or table level - bucardo, slony, ..

Comment: Hi Pavel,     even in the latest Postgres version (9.3), it built-in replication does not support per-database level, right?

Comment: @EmreHe - yes, there is not any change

Comment: it's per cluster rather than per 'server', right? You can have multiple clusters on a server and just replicate some of them.

Comment: yes, per database cluster or maybe better, per instance

Answer (score 1):

With postgres 10 some of the features of [pglogical](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/pglogical/) will be available, see https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/logical-replication-postgresql-10/ for more info.